# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: flutter

```
AnalyticsSettings call failed
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:865)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettingsData.saveSettings(AnalyticsSettings.kt:442)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings$saveSettings$1.invoke(AnalyticsSettings.kt:373)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings$saveSettings$1.invoke(AnalyticsSettings.kt:56)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.runIfAnalyticsSettingsUsable(AnalyticsSettings.kt:103)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.saveSettings(AnalyticsSettings.kt:372)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.getSalt(AnalyticsSettings.kt:360)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.Anonymizer.anonymize(Anonymizer.kt:48)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.Anonymizer.anonymizeUtf8(Anonymizer.kt:33)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ProcessProfileWriterFactory.setGlobalProperties(ProcessProfileWriterFactory.java:130)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ProcessProfileWriterFactory.initializeInternal(ProcessProfileWriterFactory.java:112)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ProcessProfileWriterFactory.initialize(ProcessProfileWriterFactory.java:91)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfilerInitializer.init(ProfilerInitializer.java:77)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.basePluginApply(BasePlugin.java:261)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.lambda$apply$0(BasePlugin.java:234)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting.runAction(crash_reporting.kt:27)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:232)
```

I got this error when I run a basic flutter project without any API calls or data operation.
Moreover, after some time project run successfully but I got this error many times.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.